# React: Open Modal from a different component

Tags: reactjs

I have a Modal component in the Main.js app and I want to trigger it from a different component (in this case Homepage, but I have one component for each page).

I don´t know how to pass a component to be rendered inside the modal.
If it helps I´m using Context API.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>this is the main app</div>
        <Modal />
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Modal.js**

```
class Modal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            'open': false
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({open: nextProps.open})
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.state.open) {
            return false
        }

        return(
            <div className="modal">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default Modal
```

**Homepage.js**

```
class Homepage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this)
    }

    handleOpenModal() {
        // here I want to open the modal and pass the <ModalContent /> component
        // basically call the <Modal open="true"> from the Main component
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="homepage">
                <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>open the modal</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const ModalContent = () => {

    return(
        <div>this is the content I want to render inside the modal</div>
    )

}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using something like `react-modal` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal)). It allows you to keep modal content right next to the trigger. It does this by appending a "portal" high up in the DOM and handles appending the content to is.

Your example may look like the following:

```
import Modal from 'react-modal';

class Homepage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { modalOpen: false };
        this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this)
    }

    handleOpenModal() {
        this.setState({ modalOpen: true });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="homepage">
                <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>open the modal</button>
                <Modal open={this.state.modalOpen}>
                  <ModalContent />
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const ModalContent = () => {

    return(
        <div>this is the content I want to render inside the modal</div>
    )

}
```